# Decode lowercase and uppercase JSON keys in Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4, jsondecoder

I have the following struct that represents a JSON:

```
struct Todo: Codable {
    let ID: Int?
    let LAST_DT_ADD: String?
    let LAST_ID:Int?
}
```

And when I use decode the same way:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
  let todo = try decoder.decode(Todo.self, from: responseData)
  completionHandler(todo, nil)
} catch {
  print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
  print(error)
  completionHandler(nil, error)
}
```

It decodes correctly, but when I have JSON items in lowercase (for example instead of `ID`, `LAST_DT_ADD` and `LAST_ID`, I have `id`, `last_dt_add` and `last_id`), it is not decoding the object. What do I have to do? How can I support uppercase and lowercase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should provide the correct version as an associated value in your `CodingKeys` enum.

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case ID = "id"
    case LAST_DT_ADD = "last_dt_add"
    case LAST_ID = "last_id"
}
```

Please note that in Swift, the convention for naming variables is standardized in camelCase and not snake_case.

Comment: sure, you are right. But when i have key in uppercase? Can i support uppercase and lowercase in decoding?

Comment: @Dmitry No, not within one coding key. Use two separate coding keys for that or write your own decoding function.